# How do I un-share a OneNote notebook?

Tags: permissions, onedrive, onenote

I recently made a notebook and wanted to share it. I used the share option and created a "View only" link for the notebook.

Now, I want to unshare it. So, I want to know how to do that.

I figured that I could just go to OneDrive and change permissions but since I shared the link, the permission currently rests with anyone who  has the link. So, if I remove permissions no one can see it. Suppose in a week, I once again want to share it with someone else, and once again generate the link ... Permissions will be regranted and everyone will be able to see it again.

So, is it possible to permanently unshare it with some people (even if I may choose to generate a share link in the future)?

I guess the easiest way of doing it is by changing the location of the notebook on the cloud.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to un-share a note book that you are sharing with another person, here`s how:

1. Hit the File tab.
2. Click Share, from the drop down column.
3. Go to, Invite people.

You should then see a list of the people who you are sharing with on the right. From there, Right click the appropriate person and you will get the option to remove or define permissions.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to File → Share → Share with people
- Click on the three dots next to *Send Link*
- Click on *Manage Access*
- You should see a list of people you have shared this notebook with and you can manage them from here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Mac version of OneNote, there is no "Manage access" functionality built-in. You must do it via the OneDrive web interface:

1. Log in to OneDrive.com
2. Click *Shared* on the left menu.
3. Find the file with the name of your OneNote notebook.
4. Right-click the file, click *Details*
5. On the side menu, under *Has access* click *Manage access*

From there you can manage and remove the list of people and links.